# How can I add an attribute to an XML node based on another attribute?

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following XML:

```
<funds>
    <fund name="A" ITEM0="7%" ITEM1="8%" ITEM2="9%" ITEM3="10%" ITEM4="11%" ITEM5="" /> 
    <fund name="B" ITEM0="11%" ITEM1="11%" ITEM2="13%" ITEM3="14%" ITEM4="16%" ITEM5="" /> 
    <fund name="C" ITEM0="" ITEM1="" ITEM2="" ITEM3="" ITEM4="" ITEM5="" /> 
    <fund name="D" ITEM0="7%" ITEM1="8%" ITEM2="9%" ITEM3="10%" ITEM4="11%" ITEM5="" /> 
    <fund name="E" ITEM0="2%" ITEM1="3%" ITEM2="3%" ITEM3="5%" ITEM4="5%" ITEM5="" /> 
    <fund name="F" ITEM0="" ITEM1="" ITEM2="" ITEM3="" ITEM4="" ITEM5="" /> 
    <fund name="G" ITEM0="3%" ITEM1="3%" ITEM2="3%" ITEM3="5%" ITEM4="5%" ITEM5="" /> 
</funds>
<ToAppend>
    <append name="A" ITEM="10" />
    <append name="B" ITEM="15" />
    <append name="C" ITEM="20" />
    <append name="D" ITEM="20" />
    <append name="E" ITEM="15" />
    <append name="F" ITEM="10" />
    <append name="G" ITEM="10" />
</ToAppend>
```

How can I loop through all of the attributes in //ToAppend/append and if 'name' is a match in //funds/fund add the attribute ITEM from //ToAppend/append to //funds/fund ?

I'm trying to append the matching items to the first list but I'm not having too much luck.  Trying to get this working via C# under the 2.0 framework.

Thanks in advance!

edit:

```
XmlNode xmlNodeInner = root.SelectSingleNode("//ToAppend/append");
XmlNode ToBeUpdated = root.SelectSingleNode("//funds/fund");

foreach (XmlElement element in ToBeUpdated)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(element.InnerXml);
       //Match the 'name' from xmlNodeInner to the 'name' of ToBeUpdated
       //if{magic occurs here and they match}
        {
            element.SetAttribute("ITEM6", "value from xmlNodeInner");
       }
    }
```

I just dont know how to do the comparison inquiry to determine if A=A, or even exists, since there is no guarentee on that.
Hopefully it would come out something like:

```
<fund name="G" ITEM0="3%" ITEM1="3%" ITEM2="3%" ITEM3="5%" ITEM4="5%" ITEM5="" ITEM6="10"/>
```

Comment: is it necessary to use LINQ?  Obviously can be done, but is it required?  Rather than someone just posting an answer, how about you post your code that doesn't work and we can help you fix it.

Comment: I removed the LINQ part... I CANT use it, just took it out to avoid possible confusion.  I would post my code but it's crap and I've been flounding around on this for a while.  I'm not even sure HOW to necessarily to the comparison.

Comment: So you'd want it to become the next (n + 1) "Item" attribute?  So if Fund name="A" has an Item5, this would become Item6?

Comment: yeah, but for right now there is a physical limit of 5 plus one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    using System;
    using System.Xml;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main( string[] args )
        {
            const string xml = @"
<root>
    <funds>
        <fund name='A' ITEM0='7%' ITEM1='8%' ITEM2='9%' ITEM3='10%' ITEM4='11%' ITEM5='' /> 
        <fund name='B' ITEM0='11%' ITEM1='11%' ITEM2='13%' ITEM3='14%' ITEM4='16%' ITEM5='' /> 
        <fund name='C' ITEM0='' ITEM1='' ITEM2='' ITEM3='' ITEM4='' ITEM5='' /> 
        <fund name='D' ITEM0='7%' ITEM1='8%' ITEM2='9%' ITEM3='10%' ITEM4='11%' ITEM5='' /> 
        <fund name='E' ITEM0='2%' ITEM1='3%' ITEM2='3%' ITEM3='5%' ITEM4='5%' ITEM5='' /> 
        <fund name='F' ITEM0='' ITEM1='' ITEM2='' ITEM3='' ITEM4='' ITEM5='' /> 
        <fund name='G' ITEM0='3%' ITEM1='3%' ITEM2='3%' ITEM3='5%' ITEM4='5%' ITEM5='' /> 
    </funds>
    <ToAppend>
        <append name='A' ITEM='10' />
        <append name='B' ITEM='15' />
        <append name='C' ITEM='20' />
        <append name='D' ITEM='20' />
        <append name='E' ITEM='15' />
        <append name='F' ITEM='10' />
        <append name='G' ITEM='10' />
    </ToAppend>
</root>
";
            // XPath that finds all "funds/fund" nodes that have a "name" attribute with the value "{0}".
            const string xpathTarget = @"//funds/fund[@name='{0}']";

            // XPath that finds all "ToAppend/append" nodes that have a "name" and "ITEM" attribute.
            const string xpathSourceNodes = @"//ToAppend/append[@name and @ITEM]";

            var doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml( xml );

            foreach ( XmlNode sourceNode in doc.SelectNodes( xpathSourceNodes ) )
            {
                string name = sourceNode.Attributes[ "name" ].Value;
                string item = sourceNode.Attributes[ "ITEM" ].Value;

                XmlNode targetNode = doc.SelectSingleNode( String.Format( xpathTarget, name ) );

                if ( null != targetNode )
                {
                    XmlAttribute newAttribute = doc.CreateAttribute( "ITEM6" );
                    newAttribute.Value = item;

                    targetNode.Attributes.Append( newAttribute );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: XPath always bites me in the backside.  Locating the targetNode was what I was pounding my head on.  Thanks!

Comment: this is generally the approach to take.  Christopher should be able to take it from here.